# Socket.io connection not work when the application is Dead

Tags: android, sockets

I have a socket connection in my app, when i minimize app and open other application then my app is dead (maybe Android OS did optimization) but app is not killed in minimize state and when i open app with task window then my socket connection gives an log this messages:

```
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 EVENT_RECONNECT_ATT
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 reconnecting
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 reconnect error
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 EVENT_RECONNECT_ATT
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 reconnecting
I/SOCKET_CON: io.socket.client.Socket@41554cb0 reconnect error
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running socket in background service and use BroadcastReciever everytime you destroy(kill) your app.

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("MyService"));
}
```

This would be your receiver.

```
public class RestartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "RestartServiceReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");
    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));

}
```

Comment: I have a background service, but i cant get event DEAD (not kill) state for app

Comment: onDestroy() of your service is called when your app gets killed. You can override it in your service

Comment: you can't get dead state, if you app is minimized it means it is running state only.

Comment: After Dead socket callback have a this Reconnect Error:
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '502 Bad Gateway'